# Can't pass non-nullable elements with *Specified double in WCF Test Client

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

I need to make a service A that can substite another service B.
I've got WSDL of B and have generated an object model.
It appears to be with XmlSerializer and for non-nullable types it follows such pattern

```
[XmlAttribute]
public DateTime Timestamp
{
  get { return this.timestampField; }
  set { this.timestampField = value; }
}

[XmlIgnore]
public bool TimestampSpecified
{
  get { return this.timestampFieldSpecified; }
  set { this.timestampFieldSpecified = value; }
}
```

After that I've built my own WCF service A which uses and exposes to outer world the same object model.
Now I want to use WCF Test Client to test my service A, but it seem that it can't handle such case with `*Specified` pattern. I can see only `Timestamp` property at "Formatted" tab and no `TimestampSpecified` that leads to default value of `DateTime` appearing inside operation contract method at server no matter what I've place in `Timestamp` (also `TimestampSpecified` is equal to `false`, but should be `true`).

Is there any workaround to make WCF Test Client to work in such scenario?

I use WCF Test Client from this folder (Visual Studio 2012) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

Comment: not getting your question

Comment: how to pass a Timestamp in decribed scenario via WCF Test Client?

Comment: u mean you want to pass null value to Timestamp ?

Comment: no I want to pass, for example, DateTime.Now or another value